# Red Apple Groundcover Dying

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

Have red apple ground cover (Aptenia cordifolia), usually very green and very hardy! However, over the past few days, it seems it has quickly been dying back. It seems to be in splotches. Is this mildew? I'm suspecting it since we just had all the rain in SoCal. Our soil may be compacted, but it doesn't seem waterlogged.

[image: Aptenia cordifolia]